# Forbid javascript library to load within an iframe

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe

I searched a lot but didn't found an answer, so i will ask you :)

So i have this wordpress website which is using a third party iframe registration process (don't ask why).

My problem is when the apply page loads (which contains the shitty iframe), the iframe has some script in it (something called runtime_hybrid.js) which sets the focus to the first visible input in the page.

My client didn't like that, and want when someone gets to the apply page to first see the top explanations. Right now the autofocus scrolls down to the "First name"...

Can you think of some way preventing this autofocus from happening? I don't have control over the iframe code, it is third party and i don't think i can mess with that).

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway it turned out that i cannout change this by any means because it is in an iframe. I tried using javascript blur() method which will remove the focus, but i can't target within the iframe.

So the solution was to use window.scrollTo(0,0) in document.ready (jquery) which happens very fast and it is like there is no scrolling at all.

Hope that will help someone.